# Why am I forking more than 5 times here?

Tags: c, fork

So I have code here, and I expected it to strictly run ls -l 5 times, but it seems to run far more times. What am I doing wrong here? I want to run ls 5 times, so I fork 5 times. Perhaps I don't understand the concept of wait properly? I went over a ton of tutorials, and none seem to tackle multiple processes using fork thoroughly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pidChilds[5];

    int i =0;

    for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        pid_t cpid = fork();
        if(cpid<0)
            printf("\n FORKED FAILED");
        if(cpid==0)
            printf("FORK SUCCESSFUL");
        pidChilds[i]=cpid;
    }





}
```

Comment: Hint: if cpid==0, do you think there's anything else you forgot to do?

Comment: @NicholasWilson Not that I can think of. :( What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use fork in C, you have to imagine the process code and state being copied into a new process, at which point it begins execution from where it left off.

When you use exec in C, you have to imagine that the entire process is replaced if the call is successful.

Here is your code, re-written to produce the expected behavior. Please read the comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t cpid;
    pid_t pidChildren[5];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cpid = fork();
        if (cpid < 0) {
            printf("fork failed\n");
        } else if (cpid == 0) {
            /*  If we arrive here, we are now in a copy of the
                state and code of the parent process. */
            printf("fork successful\n");
            break;
        } else {
            /*  We are still in the parent process. */
            pidChildren[i] = cpid;
        }
    }

    if (cpid == 0) {
        /*  We are in one of the children;
            we don't know which one. */
        char *cmd[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
        /*  If execvp is successful, this process will be
            replaced by ls. */
        if (execvp(cmd[0], cmd) < 0) {
            printf("execvp failed\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /* We expect that only the parent arrives here. */
    int exitStatus = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        waitpid(pidChildren[i], &exitStatus, 0);
        printf("Child %d exited with status %d\n", i, exitStatus);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That array is useless to each child, which will soon become `ls`. If `cpid != 0` at that point, then we know that we are in the parent process, which is the only copy of this program that really needs to populate that array. Five copies of the code above will be made in memory, only one of them is the parent where the "master work" gets done.

Comment: suppose you want to run 5 different commands back to back, i.e ls, then ls -l then pwd, why isn't that working for your code?

Comment: suppose you want to run 5 different commands back to back, i.e ls, then ls -l then pwd, why isn't that working for your code?

Comment: If you want to have each child continue past the fork with some variable stored as a unique identifier, you could use the variable `i` for that purpose. I'll let you figure it out. Read the code slowly and think about what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

You are forking in a loop and fork quasi-copies the process including the instruction-pointer.

Meaning: **eg your first child-process will find itself in a loop that still has 4 rounds to go**.

And each of the 4 processes **that** process spawns will find it has to go 3 rounds more.

And so on.

`fork()` returns whether the process you are in is the parent- or child-process. You should check that return value and `break;` the loop if you are in a child-process.

> " On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child. On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately. "

So you should `if(cpid==0) break;`.

Comment: not 120 todays, it runs about 15-20 times. I am strictly storing the pid in the child process. How can I fix my problem? for each form, there is 1 child process, and in the child process I am storing the pid

Comment: not exactly 120? dont know why, but the **solution** is clear.

Comment: I don't think your calculation is correct. The number of processes doubles at every iteration, so it should be a total of 1+2+4+8+16=31 executions of the ls command.

Comment: right. removed the 120 stuff it is irrelevant to the solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Every `i`'th `fork` starts off *inside the loop*, so it will run the remaining `n-i` iterations of that loop, forking recursively.

Comment: I have it in the loop since I expect to have 5 forks, whose children should store the pid in the child pid array for further work